# Redirect empty search to another page

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, search, rewrite-rules, 404-error

I am using the following code to change the url of my search results page:

```
function wpb_change_search_url() {
    if (is_search() && !empty($_GET['s'])) {
        wp_redirect(home_url("/suche/") . urlencode( get_query_var('s')), 301);
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpb_change_search_url');
```

It works perfectly. Now I want to redirect an empty search as well. Right now an empty search leads to `/?s=` but it should redirect to `/suche`. I managed to do the redirect but the browser shows a 404 for `/suche`.
I have tried every possible thing I could find online but nothing worked. Hopefully someone has an idea. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My permalinks structure is `/%postname%` if that might be of importance.

Comment: Show the code you are using for an empty search redirect.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, thinking about it actually solved my problem :) I have a custom search.php but forgot to add it to my pages. That's why the search_base rewrite worked but the template itself wasn't found. So problem solved thanks to you.